# Trouble using a DataTrigger with Rectangle in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, storyboard

I'm new to WPF and am trying to animate the changes to a Rectangle's size and position. I have my rectangle being set by binding it to an INotifyPropertyChanged property. This works fine but the changes can be extreme and I'd like it to be visually less jarring.

This is working fine:

```
<Rectangle Fill="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrush}" 
        Stroke="black">
<Rectangle.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=Coil.Left, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Coil.Top, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Path=Coil.Width, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Path=Coil.Height, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Style>
</Rectangle.Style>
```

Coil.Left is a RectangleF structure within my INotifyPropertyChanged object and the DataContext property of my canvas containing the rectangle is being set in my code behind after the object is created.

I've also been able to animate this using an EventTrigger just fine:

```
<Rectangle Fill="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrush}" 
        Stroke="black">
<Rectangle.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=Coil.Left, Mode=OneTime}"/>
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Coil.Top, Mode=OneTime}"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Path=Coil.Width, Mode=OneTime}"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Path=Coil.Height, Mode=OneTime}"/>
    </Style>
</Rectangle.Style>
<Rectangle.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Rectangle.MouseEnter">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" 
                                        To="{Binding Path=Coil.Width, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        Duration="0:0:5"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" 
                                        To="{Binding Path=Coil.Height, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" 
                                        To="{Binding Path=Coil.Left, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        Duration="0:0:5"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" 
                                        To="{Binding Path=Coil.Top, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        Duration="0:0:5"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
</Rectangle.Triggers>
```

When I move my mouse over the Rectangle, it changes via animation to the current property values of Coil.Left, Top, Width, and Height as expected.

However, what I want to accomplish is for any change to the Coil property values to be an animated change. So my plan was to set a DataTrigger and use a converter to return always true so that any change would result in the changes being played out via animation.

But regardless of what I do, I'm getting an exception error before it even opens the window when I use a DataTrigger and I've got no idea why this is happening. To keep it simple, I took out the converter and just used a straight value:

```
<Rectangle Fill="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrush}" 
        Stroke="black">
<Rectangle.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=Coil.Left, Mode=OneTime}"/>
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Coil.Top, Mode=OneTime}"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Path=Coil.Width, Mode=OneTime}"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Path=Coil.Height, Mode=OneTime}"/>
    </Style>
</Rectangle.Style>
<Rectangle.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Coil.Height}" Value="60">
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" 
                                        To="{Binding Path=Coil.Width, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        Duration="0:0:5"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" 
                                        To="{Binding Path=Coil.Height, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" 
                                        To="{Binding Path=Coil.Left, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        Duration="0:0:5"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" 
                                        To="{Binding Path=Coil.Top, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        Duration="0:0:5"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    </DataTrigger>
</Rectangle.Triggers>
```

Any thoughts on why this would give me an exception error? I'm sure it's just a matter of my inexperience with WPF. This is my first project.

Thank you in advance.

--John

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: The exception type is System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException

The exception reads: 'Initialization of 'System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle' threw an exception

There is an inner exception of {"Triggers collection members must be of type EventTrigger."}

Comment: Perhaps I can do something with a DataTemplate which looks to support DataTriggers... I haven't gotten that far yet in my reading.

Answer (score 0):

For a `FrameworkElement` like a `Rectangle` you can only use `EventTrigger`. In `Style`, `ControlTemplate` and `DataTemplate` you can use `Trigger` / `MultiTrigger` and `DataTrigger` / `MultiDataTrigger` too.

This means move your `DataTrigger` into `Rectangle` style and it should work:

```
<Rectangle Fill="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrush}" Stroke="Black">
    <Rectangle.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
            ... 
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Coil.Height}" Value="60">
                    ...
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
</Rectangle>
```

Comment: Thank you but I had tried that and got an exception error with that way too: 

{"'Set property 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Style' threw an exception.' Line number '120' and line position '22'."}

{"Cannot freeze this Storyboard timeline tree for use across threads."}

Comment: This is another problem for a new question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Was reading about this recently. Despite the similarity of `EventTriggers` and `DataTriggers`, you can use `Binding` inside the `Storyboard` for the `EventTrigger` but not the `DataTrigger`.

So you'll get a **System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException** error if you try using binding inside the `Storyboard` condition such as below,

```xaml
<Style.Triggers>
  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsBarVisible, 
    Converter={StaticResource myBooleanToVisibiltyConverter}}" Value="Visible">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value"
            From="{Binding Path=ProgressedAmout}"
            To="100"
            Duration="0:0:50"
          ></DoubleAnimation>
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
  </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

You can use and `EventTrigger` in return or get rid of the `Storyborad`'s `To` to `From` binding.